# Adobe AMF sometimes take long time to connect

Tags: flash, blazeds, amf

My system consists of Flash Player 11.2.202.235, Robotlegs 1.4, Spring BlazeDS Integration 1.5 (Spring 3.0, BlazeDS 4.0) and Tomcat 6.

When my Flash application requests AMF, sometimes (5%) it takes long time to connect (e.g. 9.31 s) as below, but most of the times are pretty fast (< hundred ms). Sometime it will timeout (I saw backend receive [flex.messaging.messages.CommandMessage PING, operation 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502898/418439)).

```
[BlazeDS]Deserializing AMF/HTTP request
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=null, responseURI=/1)
    (Array #0)
      [0] = (Typed Object #0 'flex.messaging.messages.CommandMessage')
        operation = 5
        correlationId = ""
        body = (Object #1)
        clientId = null
        messageId = "7C282B73-AC5A-D9DD-B77E-CCE10B1B479C"
        timeToLive = 0
        destination = ""
        timestamp = 0
        headers = (Object #2)
          DSId = "3A4FF978-3019-7B33-DF82-5A20F6187A7D"
          DSMessagingVersion = 1

[BlazeDS]Serializing AMF/HTTP response
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=/1/onResult, responseURI=)
    (Externalizable Object #0 'DSK')
      (Object #1)
        DSMessagingVersion = 1.0
        DSId = "3A4FF978-3019-7B33-DF82-5A20F6187A7D"
1.33917226495E12
(Byte Array #2, Length 16)
(Byte Array #3, Length 16)
(Byte Array #4, Length 16)
```

My question:

1. Why the connection took so long time? (**Update**: I monitored with Wireshark, some requests were not sent out until 9 seconds) It is not the first request.
2. Is my response for CommandMessage correct? I did not explicitly handle it. Is it handled by BlazeDS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd  upgrade to Tomcat7 for blazeds 4.0. The response "1/onResult" is correct though.